# UIWebView loading partial images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

In my UIWebView I am loading html page from document directory. The html page contain most of the images. But when I tried to load that page, it displays partial images, some images are cropped & it shows grey area. I have tried to cache the images but still I am facing the same issue. The dimension of the images are near about 512x673 & size is 100KB with 70dpi.

I can't find the exact issue.

Please reply if anyone have idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste me the code what you have tried?

Comment: NCXNavigationPoint* navigationPoint = [navArray.navigationPoints objectAtIndex: i-1];
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@/%@/%@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex: 0],ePubFileName,ePubFileTitle,navigationPoint.content];           NSURL *pathUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:pathUrl];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[webView loadRequest:request];